# How to get the green circle to smear?

Tags: java, animation, drawing

I am trying to do a simple animation, in which a green circle moves diagonally in a smeared pattern on a widget named `panel` which is an instance of a `class MyPanel` which extends `JPanel`.

The `JFrame` has a start button, which when pressed is supposed to start the animation by calling the `actionPerformed` method (in which I call the animate method, which calls the `repaint` method while successively incrementing the x and y coordinates of the circle) in the main class which itself is the listener.

Instead when the button is pressed, the circle shows up at the initial coordinates, and then after a delay another circle shows up at the final coordinates. Could someone please help me figure out where I am going wrong? I am a beginner in Java, who has done some basic programming in C years ago.

Thanks in advance. Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 

public class Smear implements ActionListener{ 
    JFrame frame; 
    MyPanel panel; 
    JButton button; 
    Smear animgui1; 
    int x=70; 
    int y=70; 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Smear animgui=new Smear(); 
        animgui.project(); 
        animgui.set(animgui); 
    } 

    public void set(Smear anim) { 
        animgui1=anim; 
    } 

    public void project() { 
        frame=new JFrame(); 
        panel=new MyPanel(); 
        button=new JButton("Start"); 
        button.addActionListener(this); 
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, button); 
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel); 
        frame.setSize(300,300); 
        frame.setVisible(true); 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    } 

    public void animate() { 
        while(x!=200) { 
            panel.repaint(); 
            x++; 
            y++; 
            System.out.println("++++"); 
            try { 
                Thread.sleep(50); 
            } 
            catch(Exception ex) {}; 
        } 
    } 

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) { 
        animgui1.animate(); 
    } 

    class MyPanel extends JPanel { 
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 
            g.setColor(Color.green); 
            g.fillOval(x,y,40,40); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

But at the same time, I have made another program SmearGui without that button(I removed the code pertaining to the button and the listener), and it works the way its intended to; the circle slowly moves in a smear pattern. The code for that is:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SmearGui{
    JFrame frame;
    MyPanel panel;
    //JButton button;
    SmearGui animgui1;
    int x=70;
    int y=70;

public static void main(String[] args){
        SmearGui animgui=new SmearGui();
        animgui.project();
        animgui.set(animgui);
        animgui.animate();
}
public void set(SmearGui anim){
        animgui1=anim;
}
public void project(){
        frame=new JFrame();
        panel=new MyPanel();
        //button=new JButton("Start");
        //button.addActionListener(this);
        //frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, button);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
public void animate(){
    while(x!=200){
        panel.repaint();
        x++;
        y++;
        try{
        Thread.sleep(50);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){};
}
}
/*public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        animgui1.animate();
}*/
  class MyPanel extends JPanel{
      public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillOval(x,y,40,40);
}
}
}
```

The code above places the animate method in the main itself.

Comment: Code indenting is intended to help people understand the code when reading it.  Do you *want* us to read it?

Comment: `Thread.sleep(50);`  Don't do that.  Use a Swing [`Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html).

Comment: Oh..I am sorry about that!! will take care of that from now on...and thanks!!! I have just started learning java, its been about some 20-30 days, and I haven't been through all that `~Swing Timer stuff.

Comment: Where is your attempt to implement a `Timer`?  I'd do it for you, except I'm too busy & too tired of spoon-feeding people.

Answer (score 1):

repaint is asynchronous, so your code doesn't wait for the panel to redraw before continuing. Your loop code is significantly faster than redrawing the panel. Use a swing timer which is executed on the same thread that the repaint occurs, so that you don't have this mismatch in calculation vs. redraw timings.

Comment: @ MeBigFatGuy Please refer to my above post that I edited. I used the entire code of the Smear program to create another program SmearGui but with the difference that I commented out/removed the code for the button and its listener appropriately. And, this one works, as the circle animates in a  smear like motion along the panel diagonal. So I guess, it must have something to do with that button.

Comment: @user1008995 It's not the button, it's the fact that in your second version the animation is done in the main thread, which is also the thread which does the drawing.